# Wrong inner sep in tkz-base and/or tkz-fct using \tkzLabelX and \tkzLabelY

Tags: tkz-fct, tkz-base

The example below shows that the inner sep of the labels of both axis are calculated wrong. The separation on the left side (see blue boxes) is too wide. The labels of points are not affected by this bug. Does anybody know how to fix it?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4,label style/.append
  style={font=\scriptsize}]
  \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4]
  \tkzDrawY[up space=.8]
  \tkzDrawX[right space=.8]
  \tkzLabelY[fill=blue!10]
  \tkzLabelX[fill=blue!10]
  \tkzFct[thick,domain=-4:4]{0.5**\x}
  \tkzDefPointByFct(-1.5) \tkzGetPoint{A}
  \tkzDefPointByFct(1) \tkzGetPoint{B}
  \tkzLabelPoints[below left,fill=red!10,inner sep=1pt](A,B)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: plot with wrong inner sep on labels]

Comment: pascal974 gave you the right answer. While waiting for an update, you can copy the tkz-obj-axes file from the tkz-base package and modify line 35. Then place the modified file in a texmf folder.

Comment: Thank you, @AlainMatthes!
It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `tkz-obj-axes` line 35 `%` is missing at the end of the line.

```
\tkzgetinteger{#1}%
```

I will report this to the author.

Comment: Very good remark ! a serious oversight!

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It works like a charm!